# redux-form fields parameters are empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm having some problems with `redux-form`, basically the parameters that handleSubmit pass to the function that it receives are empty...

Let me describe my files (I'll use a gist for clarity and for the sake of brevity):

1. [The stateless component](https://gist.github.com/nanotime/5e58db241f7c44fc5a7f1815aea1c16e#file-component-jsx-L2)
2. [The Container](https://gist.github.com/nanotime/5e58db241f7c44fc5a7f1815aea1c16e#file-component-jsx-L47)
3. [The reducer](https://gist.github.com/nanotime/5e58db241f7c44fc5a7f1815aea1c16e#file-component-jsx-L65)
4. [The renderLoginField](https://gist.github.com/nanotime/5e58db241f7c44fc5a7f1815aea1c16e#file-component-jsx-L83)

If you can see in this line: `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onFormSubmit.bind(this))}>`

And this ultra-simple function:

```
onFormSubmit(fields) {
  console.log(fields);
};
```

Fields are empty, but the `form` reducer is active, and exists with registered fields:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: What are the versions you're using?

Comment: @gustavohenke im using `"redux-form": "^6.4.3"`, and the object isn't undefined, is empty (shame thing for the purpose). I can't figure the problem.

Comment: Looking better at it, you forgot to show us what your `renderLoginField` function!

Comment: Done, i added the function to the gist and the link to the lines. `renderLoginField` is just a stateless component to render the form field with `redux-form/Field` component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `renderLoginField` function, which renders the custom field component (d'oh!) is not making use of the `input` prop.

Here is the properly changed code for your `renderLoginField` function:

```
const renderLoginField = ({icon, input, type, meta: { touched, error }}) => {
  let mailIcon = 'fa-envelope-o';
  let passIcon = 'fa-key';
  return (
    <div className='form-group input-group'>
      <span className='input-group-addon' id='email'>
        <i className={`fa ${icon === 'mail' ? mailIcon : passIcon}`} />
      </span>
      <input
        { ...input } // <-- missing in your code!!
        type={type}
        aria-describedby={type}
        name={input.name}
        placeholder={`Insert ${type}`}
        className='form-control'/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you check [the docs for `<Field>` component](http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/docs/api/Field.md/), you'll see the following statement, which describes how important it's to do that:

> #### Input Props
>
> **The props under the `input` key are what connects your input component to Redux**
>   and are meant to be destructured into your `<input/>` component